# javax validation for nested inherited classes

Tags: java, validation, inheritance, nested

I have a structure of java classes as inline :

Class Base

Class Base_A extends Base

```
@NotNull
List<A_item> items
```

Class Base_B extends Base

```
@NotNull
List<B_item> items
```

Class Base_item

Class A_item extends Base_item

```
@NotNull
start_date
```

Class B_item extends Base_item

```
@NotNull
quantity
```

Issue: when I use javax **validator.validate(Base_A)**, it only validates non-null "items". But it does not throw error if "start_date" is missing for the A_item object in the "items" list.

Is there a way I can resolve this (without iterating over the List<A_items> and revalidate A_item)

Comment: Hi Pinal Shah have you fixed your problem?
Can you please review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add annotation @Valid over @NotNull annotation
Please see the following example:

```
@Valid
@NotNull
List<A_item> items
```

Moreover if you use list, I would like to recommend mark it with annotation @NotEmpty